# Proving $e^z=-1\iff z=i\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm struggling about something. I have to solve the equation $e^z=-1$.

- What I've done is : $z=x+iy$. Then $$e^z=-1\iff e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))=-1\iff \begin{cases}e^x=1\\ \cos(y)=-1\\ \sin(y)=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}x=0\\ y\in (2\mathbb Z+1)\pi\end{cases},$$
  where $(2\mathbb Z+1)\pi:=\{(2k+1)\pi\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.
- However, in the solution of my lecture, they wrote $$e^z=1\iff z=i\pi,$$
  where we used the branch $[0,2\pi)$ of the complex logarithm.

The thing I don't understand, it's that I have infinitely many solutions, whereas in my lecture they have only one. My questions are probably silly, but did they have mistaken something ? or am I wrong somewhere ?

Comment: You are right, there are infinitely many solutions. Perhaps your lecture asks for *some* solution? Impossible to answer without seeing the full problem description.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, as you correctly pointed out, but I believe what they meant was that when you require that the argument be between $0$ and $2\pi,$ then $z = i\pi$ is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

They're wrong and you're right.

One is *not* allowed to say that “$e^z=-1$ if and only if $z=\log(-1)$ where one (particular) branch of the logarithm is taken”. For the simple reason that the statement is false.

It would be similar to say that $z^2=1$ if and only if $z=1$, because we take a particular branch of the square root.

What one can say is that if $z=\log(-1)$ (with the above meaning for the logarithm), then $e^z=-1$, essentially by definition. But the reverse implication is clearly false, because the exponential function is periodic.

It would

Comment: It might be worth explicitly discussing the "$[0,2\pi)$ branch" which was mentioned in the question and does not match the principal branch as some books define it. Relatedly, that the relevant $\mathrm{Log}(-1)$ is indeed $\pi i$.

Comment: @MarkS. The fact that the “principal” logarithm of $-1$ is $\pi i$ is not really relevant to the problem of finding the solutions to $e^z=-1$. It's known that, if you take *any* determination $l$ of the logarithm, the solutions are of the form $l+2k\pi i$, for $k$ any integer. About the “principal branch”, books disagree on what it should be, but I guess that $(-\pi,\pi]$ is better for several purposes.

Comment: I agree with everything in your comment, I just thought that it might better address the question in the OP of "did they have mistaken something" by discussing the details of what they said/wrote more. Just an opinion on pedagogy, rather than mathematical disagreement.

Comment: @MarkS. They say they used “the branch”, not ”the principal branch”.

Comment: Right, but your answer used the phrase "principal branch" and my concern was that it might be hard for the OP to connect what you were saying with their lecture.

Comment: @MarkS. I removed the “principal” to stick with the reported wording.